# Creating a user on exchange through LDAP

Tags: php, exchange, ldap

I have managed to use the `LDAP module` that comes standard with `PHP` to `find, add, modify, and authenticate user accounts and groups` to `Active Directory`.

The only thing that has me stumped is `creating a mailbox` for a new user in exchange.

Now I notice that people point to `ews, adLDAP, ldaptools`.

I am wondering if it is possible to just use `LDAP` to accomplish this goal. Has anyone attempted this?

Also when adding `user mailboxs` in `exchange`, back-end uses `load balancing` and automatically distributes the accounts between the available DBs, can this be utilized when adding `user mailboxes` with `php`?

Is this even possible through plain `LDAP`? if not what are my choices?

**Response to BastianW:**

I have tried using `power-shell` and executing it from my `php script`:

1- php script resides on a webserver

2-exchange resides on another server

3-the command I built to execute on `remote-exchange`:

```
$command1 =  'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command'. ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto -ClientApplication:ManagementShell; enable-mailuser -identity tmeow@comp.com -ExternalEmailAddress tmeow@comp.com";
shell_exec($command1);
```

I can run this in `power-shell` with no problem, but in `php` I can not run it successfully.

Comment: in the past I have used something like this (http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=393386)  to do that. Since I no longer manage any exchange servers I cannot verify it, but it used to work fine. Adapting the code to php should be trivial.

Comment: and according to this post in the Microsoft forum https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/WINDOWS/en-US/04bc7c24-c43d-42e8-9cf7-f5a444dc65fd/creating-exchange-2013-mailbox-with-ldap?forum=winserverManagement, yes it is possible

Comment: thank you for your response, I guess one of the issues I have is that, if i should continue to connect to DC or the exchange server. from the link you posted it seems like i should go with connecting to DC

Comment: if you want to use ldap, then you need to use the DC which is the ldap server. the libraries you do not want to use do that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use LDAP to create an Exchange Mailbox. The main reason is that the user will get an Exchange Mailbox GUI ID which can only be generated by the Exchange Subsystem (e.g. via PowerShell). 
You can't fake that one and add some random fields via LDAP.

However there are some possible options for you:

1. You could use EWS there is also a [php EWS](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews) module build.
2. You could build a webservice which is triggering some PowerShell scripts and include the webserver inside your PHP script. This is how I build a construct for multiple companies to automate their Exchange processes.

Comment: please see above

Comment: I would appreciate if you add a link for the second option.(just for reading so I get an Idea where to start)

Comment: hm, thats not that easy to explain here as the hardest part was the IIS server configuration, there is also no link out there. But I can see if I can write an proof of concept article somewhere and link it here. However as I´m currently involved in some projects I need around a month before I can start creating such an article. I will put that on my ToDo List and update this here once ready.

Comment: The remark regarding the GUID is not fully correct. The Exchange Mailbox GUID is just a v4 UUID, which can be generated by a library like `ramsey/uuid`. So you don't "fake" it, you just have to generate one properly. You don't need Windows / Exchange to do that though. It's not impossible to do through straight up LDAP, there's just a lot of things you have to account for if you go that route.